# integrate Firebase Firestore into Electron JS

Tags: firebase, webpack, electron, babeljs

I am trying to integrate firebase Firestore & storage into my electron app and I am getting errors all over the place,
I bundle the source code with electron forge and using Webpack 5 with babel
[image: first error]

[image: secund]

[image]

the weird thing is that firebase auth is working out of the box

the browser window create

```
  imageEditor = new BrowserWindow({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    ...screen.getPrimaryDisplay().size,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
    },
    transparent: true,
    frame: false,
  });

  session.defaultSession.webRequest.onHeadersReceived((details, callback) => {
    callback({
      responseHeaders: {
        ...details.responseHeaders,
        "Content-Security-Policy": [
          "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' http://localhost:9099/ https://*.googleapis.com ;object-src 'self';img-src 'self' data:",
        ],
      },
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

found the solution in the end there was problem getting the firebase modules and by adding the loader @vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader the problem is solved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).